# Linphone for Raspberry error

Tags: raspbian-stretch, sip

I finish, using source and without errors, the linphone installation on 'stretch'  following the instructions on [linphone](https://wiki.linphone.org/xwiki/wiki/public/view/Linphone/Linphone%20and%20Raspberry%20Pi/).

trying to start `linphonec', I'm receiving the following error message:

```bsh
$ linphonec
2019-07-07 21:46:59:551 mediastreamer-error-Connection to the pulseaudio server failed
2019-07-07 21:46:59:588 liblinphone-fatal-Unable to open linphone database.
Aborted
```

Even that the instructions required only `libasound2-dev` and `libpulse-dev`, after installing 'pulseaudio' the error continue.
I also search the whole disk for a `linphone.db` and the .db was not found (besides one on the `tester` directory).
Is there any missing step on the installation instructions?
<sub>**Redacted version info**</sub>

```bsh
$ python --version
Python 2.7.13
$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
$ uname -a
Linux coral 4.19.42-v7+ #1219 SMP Tue May 14 21:20:58 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.9 (stretch)
Release:        9.9
Codename:       stretch
$ c++ --version
c++ (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.1
Built for arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem under Jessie.
To solve the problem, I used :

```
strace linphonec
```

and getting the .db path, then :

```
touch /path/file.db
```

To check the sound cards (when you have resolved the creation of the .db file and linphonec want start) :

```
linphonec> help
linphonec> soundcard list
0: ALSA: default device
1: ALSA: bcm2835 ALSA
2: ALSA: Logitech USB Headset
3: PulseAudio: default
```

Linphonec work, the sound work, but I always have the pulse audio error message in the output. (I think for me it's a missing lib : libdbus in the pulseaudio directory , but the lib is correctly found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ directory after first check in pulseaudio dir., strace for more messages...)

On Stretch:

```
mkdir -pv ~/.local/share/linphone/
```

seem's to work.

Comment: Thanks, just `mkdir -pv  ~/.local/share/linphone/` was enough, linphonec completed the .db creation.
I was looking for external 'soundard' command.

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to accept the answer if it suits you.